# Managing 'IndexError' in Python NumPy arrays and matrices with probability calculations

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, probability, numpy-ndarray

So, I'm working on a college project that deals with probability and statistical events. We chose the game "Battleship," where there are only 2 positions for "targets" in a 5x5 matrix. In this way, we implemented the use of numpy to perform some calculations and provide a reasonably efficient model to avoid or hit the targets. I'll post the code here and eagerly await your help! Thank you!

The error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-3030058a9c8a> in <cell line: 142>()
    140 
    141 # Obter os pares de menor probabilidade
--> 142 pares_menor_probabilidade = obter_pares_menor_probabilidade(matriz_probabilidades)
    143 
    144 # Exibir os pares de menor probabilidade

<ipython-input-21-3030058a9c8a> in obter_pares_menor_probabilidade(matriz_probabilidades)
    113         tamanho_amostra = min(tamanho_amostra, len(numeros_disponiveis))
    114         indices_escolhidos = escolher_indices_com_probabilidades(probabilidades, tamanho_amostra)
--> 115         escolhas = np.array(numeros_disponiveis)[indices_escolhidos]
    116 
    117         # Adicionar as escolhas ao histórico de jogadas do computador

IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6
```

Comment: Please format long code strings as code blocks. You can do this by adding three backticks, eg \`\`\`code\`\`\` will produce ```code```